# Wird "Beginnerin" oft genutzt?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, single-word-request

Die weibliche Wortform für "Anfänger" ist "Anfängerin". Die weibliche Wortform für "Einsteiger" ist "Einsteigerin". Aber gibt es auch "Beginnerin" für "Beginner", und wird das oft benutzt? Ich finde es in Linguee oder Wiktionary nicht.

Comment: *Beginner* klingt für mich nach einem Anglizismus (ich würde ausschließlich *Anfänger* benutzen). Ungeachtet dessen kann man durch Anfügen der Endung *-in* die feminine Variante *Beginnerin* bilden.

Comment: [NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Beginner%2CBeginnerin%2CAnf%C3%A4nger%2CAnf%C3%A4ngerin&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=31&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CBeginner%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CBeginnerin%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CAnf%C3%A4nger%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CAnf%C3%A4ngerin%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CBeginner%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CBeginnerin%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CAnf%C3%A4nger%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CAnf%C3%A4ngerin%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Danke Björn und RDBury für ihre Antworten!

Answer (score 14):

"Beginner" ist eigentlich kein gebräuchliches deutsches Wort, ich würde das nicht benutzen, außer wenn ich über eine bestimmte Hamburger Hip-Hop-Gruppe spreche, die "Beginner" heißt (früher: "Absolute Beginner").

Es gibt das Verb "beginnen" und auch ein entsprechendes englisches Wort, deshalb wird dich vermutlich jeder verstehen, wenn du das Wort im Sinn von "Anfänger" benutzt. Vielleicht gibt es sogar Leute, die das als Anglizismus benutzen. Für mich klingt es im Deutschen nicht natürlich, und "Beginnerin" auch nicht.

EDIT: wie @Carsten S schrieb - nach einer schnellen Google-Suche scheint "Beginner" *im Web* als Anglizismus doch einigermaßen verbreitet zu sein - auf den ersten Blick wohl besonders im Bereich Sport. Es klingt vielleicht cooler als "Anfänger".

Comment: Google-Suche nach "als Beginner", mit Anführungszeichen liefert halb so viele Treffer wie "als Anfänger". Mit NGram ist der Faktor aber in der Tat eher um die zwanzig.

Comment: Und die Treffer in Büchern sind auch nicht im Sinne von Anfänger. Beispiel: "Zur Kenntnis des Werther gesellte sich dann in Europa die des Faust I und einiger Hauptwerke der Romantik, und man sah von hier aus Goethe als Beginner einer deutschen Romantik, einer Dichtung des Gefühls ."

Comment: Herzlichen Dank Halvar und Carsten für ihre Antworten!